# Pyinstaller Executable file not running properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have created executable using pyinstaller,when I run the executable file I get a blank cmd window that closes after seconds.

[Here is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBWiF.png)

The python file works properly when I run it using *python file.py* in cmd

Comment: run the exe in cmd prompt and catch the error and post it here, so that we can check the error.

Comment: can you post your python code ? without it it will be hard to help you

Answer (score 1):

if your script have no errors add an input command at the end of your script that should fix  it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

this is what I did and it works for me:

after

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

just type in terminal

```
pyinstaller -F main.py
```